WhatsApp API redirection issue on iPhone using Instagram's browser with https://wa.me link
I'm encountering a problem with automatic redirection to WhatsApp using the https://wa.me link in an eCommerce setup, which specifically affects iPhone users when accessed via the Instagram browser.
Our eCommerce platform allows customers to finalize their orders via WhatsApp. Users click on the "Place Order on WhatsApp" button, intended to redirect them directly to a WhatsApp chat with pre-filled order details. This is achieved through a link formatted as https://wa.me/?text=urlencodedtext.
On iPhones, specifically when accessed through the Instagram browser, the automatic redirection to WhatsApp does not occur. Instead of opening WhatsApp directly, users are directed to a WhatsApp screen. Upon clicking the "Go to Chat" button, they are informed that WhatsApp is not installed, despite it being already installed on the device.
Code Example:
<a href="https://wa.me/1234567890?text=I%20want%20to%20place%20an%20order">Place Order on WhatsApp</a>

I need the link to seamlessly open the WhatsApp app with the pre-filled message on iPhones, especially when accessed through the Instagram browser. The current behavior appears to be a miscommunication between the browser and the app on iOS devices.
Has anyone experienced a similar issue or knows a workaround for this specific scenario on iPhones using Instagram's browser?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
